# SSIS to SQL Server data import and conversion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am a beginner with SQL Server 2014. I need some advise with data type conversion from SSIS to SQL Server.

I am working with a `DATETIME` column, an example value is "2017-08-17 16:00:50" which is in format 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSsss'

From SSIS I have used data type `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` and in SQL Server I have used data type `NVARCHAR`.

When I am trying to import the data from SSIS, it changes the date format from 2017-08-17 16:00:50 to 17/08/2017 4:00:50 PM. How do I prevent this and also when I try and convert the varchar date to datetime format using a cast or convert like this:

With convert

```
select 
    convert(datetime, [LastUpdateDateTime], 109) as [LastUpdateDateTime]
from 
    mytable
```

I get the this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

With a cast

```
select 
    cast([LastUpdateDateTime] as datetime) as [LastUpdateDateTime]
from 
    mytable
```

I get the this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Please advise,

Comment: Where do you see "17/08/2017 4:00:50 PM "? In ths SSIS viewer? I n a preview window? in the database? are you loading it into a datetime field in the database? True dates don't have formats. It's just the tool that you're looking at will impose a format on it. Never use cast to convert a date. Use `convert` or `try_convert`, along with a datetime code from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql. Never load a date into a varchar field. Always load it into a date or datetime field

Comment: If you have a `DATETIME` - leave it as `DATETIME`, don't convert / store it as `NVARCHAR` !! Also: `DATETIME` in SQL Server has **no format** since it's an 8-byte binary value that is being stored. The formatting only happens when you need to *display the value* - and you can handle that any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use date style 103 in convert 
try this:

```
Declare @dt nvarchar(50)=CONVERT(nvarchar(50),[LastUpdateDateTime],103)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), @dt, 103)
```